# Alignment and size of C++ primitive types

Tags: c++, memory-alignment, alignof

In C++, it seems that for all integer types (`int`, `long long int`, `std::uint16_t`, ...) and for the floating point types, it is always `sizeof(T) == alignof(T)`.

Is this compiler/platform-specific, or guaranteed to be true? Could there be a platform where `int32_t`s do not need to be aligned on a 32 bit boundary (as long as they don't overlap)?

Comment: Compiler / platform specific. And yes, there *are* platforms where a 32bit integer is not required to reside on a 32bit alignment. Actually, there are platforms possible where `int32_t` does not even *exist*.

Comment: One exception to this that I've seen in the past is `sizeof(double) == 8` but `alignof(double) == 4` (I believe this is common on 32 bit platforms, probably not so much now that 64 bits is becoming the norm.)

Comment: @PaulR: The norm *for what*? You are aware that, for every 64bit desktop / server CPU, there are *thousands* of embedded 8/16 bit CPUs produced?

Comment: @DevSolar: true, although use of `double` is fairly uncommon in low-end embedded applications.

Comment: @PaulR: Sorry. Allergic reaction to "all computers are desktops" sometimes leads to canned response without brain engaging. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar: no problem - I have similar issues (e.g. everyone seems to assume that x86 is the norm, so they just say "assembly" when they actually mean x86 assembly - grrr). Not to mention US-centric assumptions about currency formats, phone numbers, date, time, etc. Anyway, don't get me started... ;-)

Comment: @PaulR: Character sets / Unicode ignorance... I hear you. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar I haven't done much embedded work at all; what kind of alignment requirements do those 8/16-bit microcontrollers have for their fundamental types?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For fundamental types, `alignof(T) == sizeof(T)` is true for most modern ABIs, but it is not guaranteed to be true.  The C++ standard leaves alignment mostly implementation-defined, subject only to these constraints (see **[basic.align]** and **[basic.fundamental]** in C++11):

- `alignof(T) <= sizeof(T)`. This is not explicit in the standard, but there is never any padding between the elements of an array, so regardless of the alignment of the first element of `T t[2]`, the *second* element cannot have alignment greater than `sizeof(T)`, and therefore that is the maximum alignment for *type* T.  Note that the alignment of a *variable* can be greater, for instance if `alignas` is used on it.
- `alignof(T) <= alignof(std::max_align_t)`, except possibly in the presence of `alignas`.  Whether `alignas` can cause "over-alignment" (to a greater granularity than `max_align_t`) is implementation-defined.
- `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` all have the same alignment requirement (namely 1, because `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition).
- All unsigned integer types have the same alignment requirement as the corresponding signed type.
- `wchar_t`, `char16_t`, and `char32_t` have the same alignment requirements as their "underlying" integer types.

There *have* been historical ABIs where fundamental types were not aligned to their size.  One well-known example is `double` and `long double` in the original System V ABI for the 80386, which were only aligned to 4-byte granularity despite being 8 and 12 bytes wide respectively.  This was because the *stack pointer* was only guaranteed to be aligned to 4-byte granularity, and it's a pain to align things within an activation record to a greater granularity than the stack pointer.<sup>1</sup>

Nowadays, this same issue of stack alignment may come up with vector types; for instance, on x86-64 the stack pointer is guaranteed to be aligned to a 16-byte boundary, but the hardware now supports up to [512-bit (64-byte) vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512).

Those are the only counterexamples I personally know about.  It would not surprise me, however, to learn that an ABI for a memory-constrained embedded environment specified *no* alignment for *anything* (that is, `alignof(T) == 1` for all T).  It's not nearly as hard for the CPU to handle that as it used to be, especially if there's no memory virtualization involved.

---

<sup>1</sup> Fun fact: the C++ standard *does not* require the implementation to have a function-call stack.  It requires support for recursion, and there's something called "stack unwinding" that happens when exceptions are thrown, but everything is carefully written so that you *could* implement it using something other than the linear stacks we're all familiar with.